# saltstack: getting started (so masterless) and wanting to use formulas

Tags: salt-stack

I'm new to saltstack and so I'm starting out serverless until I have things basically working.  But to get things basically working, I want to use formulas, which means I should specify gitfs_remotes, but that only works (it appears) on the master.

So I clone `https://github.com/my-organisation/openssh-formula.git` and move openssh-formula/openssh to /srv/salt/openssh/.

Now in `top.sls` I say

```
base:
  '*':
    - system  # sshd, git, system
```

and in `system/init.sls`, I say (among other things)

```
open_sshd_server:
  openssh
```

That fails:

```
[T] ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:vagrant $ sudo salt-call --local state.highstate
local:
    Data failed to compile:
----------
    ID open_sshd_server in SLS system is not a dictionary
[T] ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:vagrant $
```

What works, though, is to push the openssh install to the top level:

```
base:
  '*':
    - system  # not sshd, but git, system
    - openssh
```

But this is goofy, putting formula calls only at the top level is horrible and unscalable organisation.

Can anyone point me in the right thing direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [include](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/include.html#include-and-exclude) to achieve this.

```
include:
  - openssh
  - openssh.config
```

Comment: Thanks.  That is syntactically correct, but doesn't actually cause, for example, `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to change in any way I can detect.  For example, I put a comment at the beginning and it is still present after the salt run.

Comment: Well, this depends on the formula that you use. If you want the config to be applied you need to add `openssh.config`. Read [this one](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/openssh-formula). Formulas follow different approaches. This one splits itself into several smaller parts, so you can decide what you want the formula to do. I've updated the answer a little.

Comment: But this is basically how you include formulas or other states into states.

Comment: Just noticed that you use the openssh-formula of your company - the above only applies if it is a fork/mirror of the official openssh-formula, of course.

Comment: This ended up being the basic key to what I needed to do.  My confusion (in comments above) related to having made a number of other errors.  Notably, openssh.config looks at pillar data to decide whether to do anything at all, and it took me embarrassingly long to understand that.

Answer (score -1):

Your SLS file structure is fine. You don't have to put formula calls at top level.

The issue is in the state `open_sshd_server`. You can use the following structure for single package installation:

```
openssh:
  pkg.installed
```

For multiple packages installation:

```
xfce:
  pkg.installed:
    - pkgs:
       - Thunar
       - thunar-archive-plugin
       - polkit-gnome
       - xfce4-panel
       - xfce4-session
       - xfce4-settings
       - ...
```

With `pkg.installed`, you don't need any unless condition.

Comment: Thanks.  One of my tests was looking at `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to see if it was being updated.  It was not.  I thought the formula handled that, customised by the pillar data I've provided.  Am I confused or utterly wrong?

Comment: If I understand you well, that's not how saltstack works. You need to do the configuration in another state.

Comment: No, the question is about applying different formulas/states from within a state - not about installing packages.